# slow calculation of General Polynomial Equation

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make a General Polynomial Function which given the time period to calculate it, the highest Polynomial power `powr`, and each constant `a`; which `a` and `powr` are the same length.

My approach of the code is the following: where each element of `time` is transformed into a vector from `powr` then when multiplied element by element with `a`, then calculating the sum of the resulting vector to make it one element.

```matlab
for i=1:length(time) 
    result(i)=sum((time(i).^[powr]).*[a]);
end
```

Problem is that It takes way too long to do this calculation the more elements `time` has and/or the longer `a` and `powr` are. Is there a way to do this calculation faster ?

Comment: forgot to add, but maybe it's useless info: `powr=Highest_Power:-1:0;` and `a` is defined by the user.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Comment: Just an FYI, MATLAB has a dedicated polynomial evaluation function called `polyval`. All it needs is a query vector (values at which to evaluate polynomial) and a vector of coefficients in descending order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Armia:

The reason the code runs slowly is that the computation is not polynomially factored, meaning that it doesn't take advantage of the running products. Say for example your polynomial is of degree 3 (i.e., `y = a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d`). The way your code is set up makes it so that `x` (analogous to your `time` variable) would first be cubed (3 multiplications + 1 to multiply by `a`), then squared (2 multiplications + 1 to multiply by `b`), then referenced (0 multiplications + 1 to multiply by `c`), and finally, you add `d`. This amounts to 9 multiplications and 3 additions. Evaluating polynomials this way requires `sum(1:n)` multiplications and `n` additions.

If instead one factors the polynomial as: `y = ((a*x + b)*x + c)*x + d` the number of multiplications goes down to 3 (from 9) and the additions remain at 3. In fact, the polynomial factoring approach evaluates the polynomial with `n` multiplications and `n` additions (`n` is the order of the polynomial). Thus, one can see that polynomial factoring scales in computational effort significantly slower than, let's call it, the brute force approach.

To do this for higher degree polynomials, I suggest you modify the code to:

```
N = length(time); %Get number of time values on which the polynomial evaluation is needed.
hmp = length(a); %I'm assuming a contains the polynomial coefficients in ascending order.
result = ones(N,1)*a(end); %Preallocate memory for results.
for i=hmp-1:-1:1
    result = result.*time + a(i); %Compute the factored parenthesis 'outward'
end
```

Where `N` is the number of time values at which you want to evaluate the polynomial, `hmp` is the highest magnitude power. Making `result` a vector makes the loop compute the polynomial for all your time entries simultaneously. This `for` loop takes advantage of polynomial factoring, which will scale much more lovely than unnecessarily having to compute powers from scratch element by element.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I didn't know that multiplication takes a a lot of time before reading this,

Comment: Happy to help. Multiplication is a modestly expensive computation. The problem lies in how quickly the number of them scales up with the order of the polynomial. For example, if you "brute-force" evaluate a 100th-order polynomial, `sum(1:100)` returns 5050, which is 50.5 times the effort of polynomial factoring.